# Jenkins: Link between Stacktrace and GitLab

Tags: python, jenkins, gitlab, pytest

We use Jenkins and GitLab in our company. We use py.test to create the XML output for Jenkins which gets rendered by the jUnit Jenkins Plugin.

The stacktraces of exceptions are pure ascii up to now. It would be really great if we could hook into Jenkins somehow and show hyperlinks to our gitlab server instead of a html pre block.

In our case we it would be enough to filter the every line of the test output and use a regular expression on it....

Example output of the Jenkins jUnit Plugin:

```
File "/home/modwork_ems_d66/src/foo/foo/utils/testutils.py", line 975, in wrapped
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/modwork_ems_d66/src/foo/foo/tests/FooTest.py", line 641, in test_empty_models_if_unused
    models))
```

I want a hyperlink to the server hosting the git repo of "foo". In our case this would be "`https://source/repos/foo/files/master/foo/foo/tests/FooTest.py`"

How to get this done? I know how to use regular expressions. The question is how to hook the regex into jenkins.

Here is a screenshot to visualize it
[image]

I want to this link on the TestReport of a single test. The URL pattern of these pages:

```
https://jenkins/job/ci_foo_bar/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/src.myapp.myapp.tests.test_tree/TestCase/test_something/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can acquire exception output after testing process you can implement a parser which prepare a simple html report for you as a build-step.

A a simplest way you can implement just a regular expression with sed like

```
sed -e 's@"/home/modwork_ems_d66/src\(.*\?\)"@<a href="https://source/repos/foo/files/master\1">\1</a>@' exceptions.txt
```

which operates on the exception file.

Comment: I know how to do regex-stuff. The question is where to hook this into jenkins.

Comment: It's answered - you could prepare html report with this links. And publish it in a way you like. I.e with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Comment: @ScyTrase: From the plugin page: "HtmlPublisher plugin is useful to publish the html reports that your build generates to the job and build pages." I guess this plugin can't create HTML output of the TestReport of a single page. I updated the question.

Comment: Let me clarify. Do you want to hook into rendering of the report, generated by 3rd-party plugin?

Comment: If yes - also provide a name of that plugin

Comment: sorry, I am new to jenkins. Yes, I want to modify the output of a plugin: jUnit. That's the plugin which shows the stacktrace.

Comment: As soon as <pre/> is hardcoded to the template (see https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/tasks/junit/CaseResult/index.jelly#L83), I think it is not possible quickly. The options are to override plugin (build you own ontop of it), propose flexibility patch to plugin (hard to imagine) or use another plugin to render stacktraces

Comment: @guettli can you try to hook that regular expression in post build action.